# Same location with different proxy urls nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, request

We am trying to get nexus via nginx reverse proxy working as a private registry for docker images. We are able to perform all the operations such as pull,search and tag but not able to push to nexus registry .

Below is the nginx configuration under location block.

```
    location ~ ^/(v1|v2)/
    {

            access_log              /var/log/nginx/docker.log;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
            proxy_pass              http://server908.int.org.com:5555;
            proxy_read_timeout      90;
    }
```

We are able to search and pull images.

```
x.x.x.x - admin [23/Jun/2017:14:31:20 +0800] "GET /v1/search?q=fedora&n=25 HTTP/1.1" 200 3733 "-" "docker/1.12.6 go/go1.7.4 kernel/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \x5C(linux\x5C))"
```

---

```
x.x.x.x - admin [23/Jun/2017:14:31:39 +0800] "GET /v2/fedora/apache/manifests/latest HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "docker/1.12.6 go/go1.7.4 kernel/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \x5C(linux\x5C))"
x.x.x.x - admin [23/Jun/2017:14:31:40 +0800] "GET /v2/fedora/apache/manifests/sha256:8531786520bb57b155bbb39d3c670dceab554b9c4ccdb556ccfbe89b23df414c HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "docker/1.12.6 go/go1.7.4 kernel/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \x5C(linux\x5C))"
x.x.x.x - admin [23/Jun/2017:14:31:40 +0800] "GET /v2/fedora/apache/blobs/sha256:c786010769a8fc7975e72c2b78f902425a6387fb5dda8852b3be2849e979e290 HTTP/1.1" 200 4094 "-" "docker/1.12.6 go/go1.7.4 kernel/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \x5C(linux\x5C))"
x.x.x.x - admin [23/Jun/2017:14:31:40 +0800] "GET /v2/fedora/apache/blobs/sha256:4e81794d88f1b28cc1653df183400d08647143123a3f141fc8cab7cd97fc75e3 HTTP/1.1" 200 294 "-" "docker/1.12.6 go/go1.7.4 kernel/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \x5C(linux\x5C))"
x.x.x.x - admin [23/Jun/2017:14:31:40 +0800] "GET /v2/fedora/apache/blobs/sha256:40da690b349860b5b2cf7cee231c21a04f1461a77ee542b77a2345412f521ae0 HTTP/1.1" 200 183 "-" "docker/1.12.6 go/go1.7.4 kernel/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \x5C(linux\x5C))"
x.x.x.x - admin [23/Jun/2017:14:31:40 +0800] "GET /v2/fedora/apache/blobs/sha256:ebb42f0b0e1ad2d2ae815a6615b95bb59b925710df3db4b8fdb2f9fdaa14a806 HTTP/1.1" 200 294 "-" "docker/1.12.6 go/go1.7.4 kernel/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \x5C(linux\x5C))"
x.x.x.x - admin [23/Jun/2017:14:31:42 +0800] "GET /v2/fedora/apache/blobs/sha256:8eea4f8b1da3e8c0848778a69e4ee73ad474a7be35fcc5ce7784a0b64ce711a7 HTTP/1.1" 200 57816237 "-" "docker/1.12.6 go/go1.7.4 kernel/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \x5C(linux\x5C))"
```

But with push we face below error.

```
x.x.x.x - admin [23/Jun/2017:14:32:34 +0800] "POST /v2/fedora/apache/blobs/uploads/?from=fedora%2Fssh&mount=sha256%3Aacd6cf67daf4cd1fcff55ece5a906a45e1569b81271b80136a1f5fecfa4546ed HTTP/1.1" 404 717 "-" "docker/1.12.6 go/go1.7.4 kernel/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \x5C(linux\x5C))"
```

when we try with proxy _pass url as http://server908.int.org.com:4444, we are able to push but cant pull the images .

Is it possible in nginx to pass two different proxy_pass urls under the same location but for different request methods . Any help would be really great ..Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx proxy by Request Method](https://serverfault.com/questions/152745/nginx-proxy-by-request-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now with below location configuration.

```
location / {

  access_log              /var/log/nginx/docker.log;
  proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    if ($request_method !~* GET) {
            proxy_pass              http://server908.int.org.com:4444;
    }
    if ($request_method = GET) {
            proxy_pass              http://server908.int.org.com:5555;
    }
  proxy_read_timeout      90;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

With Nginx you can catch the method used in the request.

So you just have to make some adjustements for redirect on the right proxy.

```
location /blabla  {
   if ($request_method = POST ) {
      # Proxy for POST
   }

  if ($request_method = GET ) {
     # Proxy for GET 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks . Your solution helped me in getting it to work with minor tweaks . I have mentioned it in my answer

Comment: @Alim So vote up the answer, that's how this site works.