# try_files inside of nginx if breaks logic

Tags: nginx

I wanna make nginx.conf that:
 - on post proxy_pass on different port
 - on get returns static files with index.html (serves SPA)

How do I make that, currently I have:

**nginx.conf**:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    include mime.types;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    upstream nodejs {

        server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    }


    server {

        listen 3000;

        charset utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 5M;

        location / {

            if ($request_method = POST ) {

                proxy_pass http://nodejs;
            }

            if ($request_method = GET ) {

                root /usr/src/app;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

> nginx: [emerg] "try_files" directive is not allowed here in
>   /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:41

Comment: You probably don't need both `if` blocks - just remove the second `if` block and place the `root` and `try_files` statements in `location` context.

Answer (score 3):

To quote *nginx HTTP server*, fourth edition (Packt publishing):

> You might wonder: *What are the advantages of using a `location` block over an `if` block?* (...) [T]he main difference lies within the directives that can be employed within
>   either block. Some can be inserted in an `if` block, and some can't; on the contrary, almost all directives are authorized within a `location` block.

So I'm afraid `try_files` is one of those directives that is allowed in a `location` block but not in an `if` block.

As for how to work around this problem and do what you want to do, I don't (yet) have an answer for that.

Comment: Can I use [this](https://serverfault.com/a/823053/304770) answer? I didn't find a way to eject try_files into upstream.

Comment: Wow! That answer used some creative thinking to solve the problem! Thanks for sharing that, @deathangel908!